# Error prolog polynomial

Tags: prolog, polynomials

I’m trying to write a polynomial in prolog where I study the grade of each variable. My problem is that when I do the validation, the problem doesn’t consider the minus as sign of the coefficient. For example, -4*x is considered as 4*x and the minus expired. I put the code where I also study a simple monomial. Can you help me?

```
as_monomial(X, m(X, 0, [])) :- number(X), !.
as_monomial(^(Y, Z), m(1, Z, [v(Z, Y)])) :- !.
as_monomial(*(X, ^(Y, Z)), m(G, K, Q)) :- as_monomial(X, m(G, TD, Vars)), K is (TD + Z), ordina_m([v(Z, Y)| Vars], Q), !.
as_monomial(*(X, Y), m(G, K, Q)) :- as_monomial(X, m(G, TD, Vars)), K is (TD + 1), ordina_m([v(1, Y)| Vars], Q), !.
as_monomial(X, m(1, 1, [v(1, X)])).

ordina_m(List, Sorted) :- sort(2, @=<, List,  Sorted).
ordina_poly(List, Sorted) :- sort(2, @>=, List,  Sorted).

is_monomial(m(_C, TD, VPs)) :- integer(TD), TD >= 0, is_list(VPs).

as_polynomial(+(X, Y), poly(D)) :- as_monomial(Y, Q), is_monomial(Q), as_polynomial(X, poly(Qs)), ordina_poly([Q| Qs], D), !.
as_polynomial(-(X, Y), poly(D)) :- as_monomial(Y, Q), is_monomial(Q), as_polynomial(X, poly(Qs)), ordina_poly([Q| Qs], D), !.
as_polynomial(X, poly([Q])) :- as_monomial(X, Q), is_monomial(Q).
```

Example:

```
?- as_polynomial(4*y^6-4*d,Q).
Output:
Q = poly([m(4, 6, [v(6, y)]), m(4, 1, [v(1, d)])]).
Real output:
Q = poly([m(4, 6, [v(6, y)]), m(-4, 1, [v(1, d)])]).
```

Where "-4" is the coefficient, "1" is totaldegree, and the list is the other variables.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You "expired" the minus yourself in the second clause of `as_polynomial/2`. Do you notice that the bodies of:

```
as_polynomial(+(X, Y), poly(D)) :- ...
```

and

```
as_polynomial(-(X, Y), poly(D)) :- ...
```

are identical?

You probably need to pass the minus to your `as_monomial(-Y, Q)` instead of `as_monomial(Y, Q)` and treat the term `-X` in another clause of `as_monomial/2`.

There is a whole bunch of cuts and I have the feeling most of them are not necessary, esp. if you know that in `*(A, B)`, `A` is a number and `B` and atom, or that in `^(A, B)`, `A` is an atom and `B` is a number.

Comment: I agree with the cuts. It is only a trial and I will correct it later. Basically I understand your idea but I'm trying to do a new clause to treat -X and I have no idea how to do it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I solve the problem treating the -X in this way! I put a new clause in the program, so I had:

```
........

as_monomial(*(X, Y), m(G, K, Q)) :- as_monomial(X, m(G, TD, Vars)), K is (TD + 1), ordina_m([v(1, Y)| Vars], Q), !.

as_monomial(-(X), m(Q, Y, L)) :- as_monomial(X, m(A, Y, L)), Q is A *(-1), !.

as_monomial(X, m(1, 1, [v(1, X)])).

.......

as_polynomial(-(X, Y), poly(D)) :- as_monomial(-Y, Q), is_monomial(Q), as_polynomial(X, poly(Qs)), ordina_poly([Q| Qs], D), !.
```

Comment: Great, this is pretty much what my answer was suggesting. I am glad you managed to get the code working without further help!

Comment: You can get rid of the `Q is A*(-1)` completely, just write `as_monomial(-X, m(-A, Y, L)) :- as_monomial(X, m(A, Y, L)).`

Comment: Thanks Boris, you are amazing

Comment: You were able to clearly describe your problem; your question had enough detail for me to reproduce it and spot the error; you took an advice and turned it into working code. You are easily in the top 1% of people using Stackoverflow already. Keep up the good work!